# Disjunction in weakened Robinson arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic

Let $ T $ denote the theory obtained by removing the axiom $ \forall x ( x = 0 \lor \exists y \, S y = x ) $ and restricting double negation elimination to disjunction-free formulas of Robinson arithmetic. In other words, $ T $ is axiomatized over intuitionistic logic by arithmetical axioms of Robinson arithmetic other than $ \forall x ( x = 0 \lor \exists y \, S y = x ) $, and double negation elimination for disjunction-free formulas.

I've been playing around with $ T $ for quite a while (actually months, on and off), and it seems that no *genuine* theorems containing a positive disjunction can be proven in $ T $. By *genuine* I mean those theorems that are not proven by mere logic, like those of the form $ A \rightarrow A \lor B $, or $ A \lor B \rightarrow C \lor D $ where $ A $ implies $ C $ and $ B $ implies $ D $. For example, I couldn't find any way of proving $ \forall x ( x < 2 \rightarrow x = 0 \lor x = 1 ) $. As neither induction nor classical logic is at hand, non of the usual ways of thinking seems to work, at least as far as I could check. I'm really not sure about unprovability of this sentence, as I couldn't find any useful method to show that it's not provable.

So to avoid any possible complexity that could come from considering more general theorems containing positive disjunctions, I ask my question like this:

> Is there a method for showing that $ \forall x ( \exists y \, x + S y = 2 \rightarrow x = 0 \lor x = 1 ) $ is provable/unprovable in $ T $?

**EDIT:**

After @MattF.'s comment, I'm inclined to add that I've been investigating theories other that $ T $, too. For example by adding to $ T $ the axiom $ \forall x ( x \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists y \, S y = x ) $, or other disjunction-free axioms. It's obvious that in the presence of classical logic, these extra axioms trivially imply the above sentence. I first thought that it would be better not to mention these other theories, to keep the question simpler. But if answering the question is easier for these theories than for $ T $, it is desired as well.

**EDIT:**

To make my thoughts even clearer, I've become suspicious that in the absence of classical logic and extra axioms containing positive disjunctions, the source of all genuine arithmetical theorems containing positive disjunctions is the axiom $ \forall x ( x = 0 \lor \exists y \, S y = x ) $. So I could ask my question like this:

> Is there a set $ \Gamma $ of disjunction-free axioms such that $ T + \Gamma \vdash \forall x ( x < 2 \rightarrow x = 0 \lor x = 1 ) $?

Comment: Does "double negation elimination for disjunction-free formulas" include the implication "\neg \neg (\exists y \ Sy=x) \to (\exists y\ Sy = x)$?

Comment: How do you prove this statement from this axiomatization using classical logic?

Comment: @MattF. Yes, it includes that implication.
$\quad$
I don't know if I can prove it from these axioms using classical logic. The mention of classical logic in the "at hand" part of the post was due to the fact that I've been investigating theories other than $T$, too. For example, by adding to $T$ the axiom $x\ne0\to\exists y\,Sy=x$ and other disjunction-free axioms. In the presence of classical logic, those trivially lead to proving the statement. I thought it would be better to keep things simpler by not mentioning those theories. But an answer addressing those theories is desired as well.

Comment: It is a general fact about intuitionistic logic that disjunction-free theories have the disjunction property. Thus, assuming $T+\Gamma\vdash\forall x\,(x<2\to x=0\lor x=1)$, let $c$ be a fresh constant; the disjunction-free theory $T+\Gamma+c<2$ proves $c=0\lor c=1$, hence by the DP, it proves $c=0$ or $c=1$. Thus, $T+\Gamma$ proves $\forall x\,(x<2\to x=0)$ or $\forall x\,(x<2\to x=1)$. Hopefully, $T$ still proves $0<2$, $1<2$, and $0\ne1$, which means $T+\Gamma$ is inconsistent.

Comment: (More generally, the disjunction property holds for “$\lor$-Harrop” theories: axiomatized by formulas in which disjunction can only occur inside antecedents of implications.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Well, the logic of $T+\Gamma$ is not exactly intuitionistic logic, as it has axioms of the form $\neg\neg A\to A$ for disjunction-free $A$. These axioms are not readily realizable, and similar considerations seem to suggest that other usual techniques of proving disjunction property (Kleene-Aczels'slash, adding nodes as roots of Kripke models, an such) won't work either. Will you please illustrate how to prove disjunction property in this case?

Comment: The axioms $\neg\neg A\to A$ are $\lor$-free, hence the result applies to them. And the general statement can be proved in the same way as the more commonly stated fact that theories axiomatized by Harrop formulas have the DP: by induction on the size of a cut-free proof in the intuitionistic sequent calculs allowing at most one formula in the succedent. (Some variant of Kleene’s slash likely works, too, if you make $\exists$ “non-constructive”. That is, redefine $|\exists x\,\phi$ as $\exists x\,|\phi$.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I got it. Thanks.

Comment: On second thought, I’m not sure the Kleene slash argument will work. But in any case, the proof using cut-free sequent calculus is quite simple.

Comment: If you have nothing like this axiom then many semi rings will be models (eg the non-negative reals or rationals), so you can’t hope to prove much.